# Can "7 deadly sins/virtues" be explained in terms of brain hormone level or receptor mutations?

Tags: neuroscience, abnormal-psychology, psychiatry, cognitive-neuroscience

I'm thinking about this question on biology.se: [do hormones make men think of sex?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9737/do-hormones-make-men-think-of-sex)

From the interview linked in the answer, I get two takeaways: a man who lost most testosterone for 4 months mentioned more humility, while a lgbt person on testosterone therapy reported more intense sexual thoughts or urges.

With this in mind, I'm thinking of the Christian concept of " deadly sins" and their opposite virtues. From a purely historic perceptive, I take recurring accounts of these phenomena in writing to say that these traits have existed for the last couple thousand years or more in the western world.

**Is modern science any closer to explaining the phenomena like wrath, sloth, gluttony or humility in terms of neurotransmitter, hormone, receptor mutations or other genetic mutations?**

Here's the kind of answer I'm looking for:

( from [serotonin receptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serotonin_receptor) )

> Deceased suicidal and otherwise depressed patients have had more
>   5-HT2A receptors than normal patients. These findings suggest that
>   post-synaptic 5-HT2A overdensity is involved in the pathogenesis of
>   depression.[4]

Comment: Part of your answer could be explained here in regards to testosterone: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/what-causes-lack-of-energy-the-relative-importance-of-testosterone-versus-emoti/4322#4322

Comment: However, essentially the answer to your question is....very slowly.  There are some studies that do focus in on those phenomenon but I don't think there's enough space in an answer box to answer your question fully....its a bit too broad.

Comment: Found this related talk. It does not mention neurotransmitters however http://www.ted.com/talks/paul_piff_does_money_make_you_mean.html