# Personality Models: The Big Five, the Seven Deadly Sins, and?

Tags: personality

In Christian tradition, there are said to be "[seven deadly sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins)": Lust, Gluttony, Greed, Sloth, Wrath, Envy, and Pride.

In Catholicism specifically, there are sometimes said to be seven virtues, each sin having an opposite: Chastity, Temperance, Charity, Diligence, Patience, Kindness, and Humility.

In a sense, this is a personality model. (Each sin/virtue duality can be thought of as a spectrum, with the sin lying at one end, and the virtue at the other. In the middle would be the "average" soul.)

In psychology, the ["Big Five" traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) come to mind, with the acronym "OCEAN": Openness to Experience, Conscientiousness, Extraversion, Agreeableness, and Neuroticism.

What other major personality models are out there that use 3-9 axes (plural of axis) to describe an individual's personality?

---

Related questions that floated about:

- [The 7 Deadlies and Hormones/Receptors](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/can-7-deadly-sins-virtues-be-explained-in-terms-of-brain-hormone-level-or-rece)
- [Why are the Big 5 not orthogonal?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/why-are-the-big-five-factors-of-personality-correlated)
- [Connections between theories of personality](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/connections-between-different-theories-of-personality)

---

**Other clues (quotes and links:)**

[Big Five Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) on the context of the Big Five:

> The Big five personality traits was the model to comprehend the relationship between personality and academic behaviors.
>   [...]

[Tao Te Ching](http://www.taoism.net/ttc/complete.htm), Chapter 15:

> Hesitant, like crossing a wintry river
>   Cautious, like fearing four neighbors
>   Solemn, like a guest
>   Loose, like ice about to melt
>   Genuine, like plain wood
>   Open, like a valley
>   Opaque, like muddy water

[Wikipedia Article: "Facet" (Psychology), a concept within the Big Five personality model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facet_(psychology))

[Wikipedia Article: Six Values in Positive Psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Values_in_Action_Inventory_of_Strengths):

1. Wisdom and Knowledge
2. Courage
3. Humanity
4. Justice
5. Temperance
6. Transcendence

Neurotransmitter/Receptor types/systems:

- Dopamine
- Serotonin
- Cannabinoid
- GABA
- Adrenergic (Epinephrine/Norepinephrine)
- Nicotinic
- ???

Comment: There are several personality models. However, you need to consider the following: purpose, age, and culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your definition of 'personality model' there are plenty to choose from.

I don't have any good overview of similarities and differences, which are tests more than models, or which are really two names on the same model.

- Big 5/5 factor model. 5x6 axes. Tests include NEO-PI, MMPI-2, IPIP ++.
- Global 5. 5 axes
- BELBIN
- Emneagram/RHETI
- Hexaco
- Holland COdes/RIASEC
- Jung/MBTI/Kiersey/DISC, 16 PF, MENTI. 4 axes
- MOTIV
- R-Drive
- Temperaments. 4 axes
- Hartman. 4 axes
- Kolb/Mumford
- Learning styles, Grasha­Riechmann styles, Dunn and Dunn styles, Canfield styles

Which ones you should focus on depends on what you are looking for.

Big 5\NEO-PI-R is the most scientifically supported model, so I mostly keep to that one. The hard part about Big 5 is the number of traits total (30), which takes a while to really learn, understand and remember. 
MBTI is useful in learning theory about personality types, differences and traits, but it lacks scientific support. 
The others I haven't studied much yet.

In general I think it's a good idea to use Big 5 as the base, and search for correlations with traits from Big 5.

Sources:

http://similarminds.com/personality_types.html
http://tcc.kcc.hawaii.edu/previous/TCC%202005/santo.pdf
http://www.personalityresearch.org/bigfive.html
http://hexaco.org/scaledescriptions

Comment: Where do the "7 deadly sins" come out in OCEAN?